# How to convert empty spaces into null values, using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, null, is-empty

I have a table and the columns on this table contains empty spaces for some records. Now I need to move the data to another table and replace the empty spaces with a `NULL` value.

I tried to use:

```
REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(col1)),' ',NULL)
```

but it doesn't work. It will convert all of the values of `col1` to `NULL`. I just want to convert only those values that have empty spaces to `NULL`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1 = NULL 
WHERE col1 = ''
```

As the commenters point out, you don't have to do `ltrim()` or `rtrim()`, and `NULL` columns will not match `''`.

Comment: You don't even need to use RTRIM. SQL Server ignores trailing whitespace when comparing strings.

Comment: @Bennor McCarthy: wow, I'm really slipping...going to drop that clause now

Comment: Not really a major problem. It's not like performance or use of indexes is really a concern for the query. Your answer was still correct anyway. :)

Comment: This will fail if the table has a constraint to disallow empty strings (which is a good idea if you are using only nulls). It's better to remove the empty strings during the copy with the NULLIF function.

Comment: @MikeKulls: he seems to imply that that the table has no such constraints. Personally I always try to avoid `NULL` in data records, because then the program logic has to watch out for them.

Comment: @egrunin: Either way you do it you should have a constraint to ensure you are consistant. He is using NULL in this table so should have a constraint to ensure nothing is an empty string. Even if he doesn't currently there is the chance it could be added in the future but only if it is done during the copy. This is a simpler faster way to do it anyway because it is done in one step.

Comment: Hello, Is there any settings to turn it on globally to force SQL server to consider nulls as empty string ? I am migrating from Sybase IQ, which considers nulls and empty strings, to SQL server and that makes things difficult in SQL server :/

Answer (score 181):

I solved a similar problem using `NULLIF` function:

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1 = NULLIF(col1, '')
```

[From the T-SQL reference:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

> NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression.

Comment: The major downside to this is that all rows in the table will be updated instead of just the rows which need the change.

Comment: This is a good option if you're also making other updates to the column when there's a non-empty string, or if you're using it in an `INSERT` statement

Answer (score 41):

SQL Server ignores trailing whitespace when comparing strings, so '   ' = ''. Just use the following query for your update

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = NULL
WHERE col1 = ''
```

NULL values in your table will stay NULL, and col1s with any number on space only characters will be changed to NULL.

If you want to do it during your copy from one table to another, use this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable ( col1, othercolumn )
SELECT
   NULLIF(col1, ''),
   othercolumn
FROM table
```

Comment: IMO this is the best answer. The question asked how to convert the empty strings to null during the copy. The accepted answer is not good because it does it in 2 steps which is not only less efficient but stops the DBA adding a constraint to ensure there are no empty strings.

Comment: I agree that the second query here really is the answer which best matches the question, even though my answer was the accepted one.

Answer (score 17):

This code generates some SQL which can achieve this on every table and column in the database:

```
SELECT
   'UPDATE ['+T.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].[' + T.TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = NULL 
   WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = '''''
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns C
INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON C.TABLE_NAME=T.TABLE_NAME AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA=T.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE 
    DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar')
AND C.IS_NULLABLE='YES'
AND T.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: your script is great, also you can add:
` WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] ' + 'NOT LIKE ' + '''%[a-z,0-9]%''' `

Comment: Thanks, what does that regex do?

Answer (score 13):

A case statement should do the trick when selecting from your source table:

```
CASE
  WHEN col1 = ' ' THEN NULL
  ELSE col1
END col1
```

Also, one thing to note is that your LTRIM and RTRIM reduce the value from a space (' ') to blank ('').  If you need to remove white space, then the case statement should be modified appropriately:

```
CASE
  WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(col1)) = '' THEN NULL
  ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(col1))
END col1
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like this?

```
UPDATE [MyTable]
SET [SomeField] = NULL
WHERE [SomeField] is not NULL
AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM([SomeField]))) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a regex one for ya.

```
update table
set col1=null
where col1 not like '%[a-z,0-9]%'
```

essentially finds any columns that dont have letters or numbers in them and sets it to null.  might have to update if you have columns with just special characters.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question as to why this is a bad idea.