# Replace empty strings with null values

Tags: string, postgresql, replace, null, plpgsql

I am rolling up a huge table by counts into a new table, where I want to change all the empty strings to `NULL`, and typecast some columns as well. I read through some of the posts and I could not find a query, which would let me do it across all the columns in a single query, without using multiple statements.

Let me know if it is possible for me to iterate across all columns and replace cells with empty strings with null.

Ref: [How to convert empty spaces into null values, using SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701812/convert-empty-space-to-null)

Comment: SELECT CAST(nullif(<column>, '') AS integer); and iterating it over the columns seems to work.

Comment: You did not mention a conversion to integer in the question.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge there is no built-in function to replace empty strings across all columns of a table. You can write a [**plpgsql function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) to take care of that.

The following function replaces empty strings **in all basic character-type columns of a given table** with `NULL`. You can then cast to `integer` if the remaining strings are valid number literals.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_empty_text_to_null(_tbl regclass, OUT updated_rows int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _typ  CONSTANT regtype[] := '{text, bpchar, varchar}';  -- ARRAY of all basic character types
   _sql  text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql                       -- build SQL command
          'UPDATE ' || _tbl
          || E'\nSET    ' || string_agg(format('%1$s = NULLIF(%1$s, '''')', col), E'\n      ,')
          || E'\nWHERE  ' || string_agg(col || ' = ''''', ' OR ')
   FROM  (
      SELECT quote_ident(attname) AS col
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl              -- valid, visible, legal table name 
      AND    attnum >= 1                  -- exclude tableoid & friends
      AND    NOT attisdropped             -- exclude dropped columns
      AND    NOT attnotnull               -- exclude columns defined NOT NULL!
      AND    atttypid = ANY(_typ)         -- only character types
      ORDER  BY attnum
      ) sub;

   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- test?

   -- Execute
   IF _sql IS NULL THEN
      updated_rows := 0;                        -- nothing to update
   ELSE
      EXECUTE _sql;
      GET DIAGNOSTICS updated_rows = ROW_COUNT; -- Report number of affected rows
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_empty2null('mytable');
SELECT f_empty2null('myschema.mytable');
```

To also get the column name `updated_rows`:

```
SELECT * FROM f_empty2null('mytable');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3054a53120ea6e184b24ecd4ac8bc04d)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b55c/1)</sub>

#### Major points

- Table name has to be valid and visible and the calling user must have all necessary privileges. If any of these conditions are not met, the function will do nothing - i.e. nothing can be destroyed, either. I cast to the [object identifier type `regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) to make sure of it.
  The table name can be supplied as is (`'mytable'`), then the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) decides. Or schema-qualified to pick a certain schema (`'myschema.mytable'`).
- Query the system catalog to get all ([character-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)) columns of the table. The provided function uses these basic [character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html): `text`, `bpchar`, `varchar`, `"char"`. Only relevant columns are processed.
- Use [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) or `format()` to sanitize column names and [safeguard against SQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860).
- The updated version uses the basic SQL aggregate function `string_agg()` to build the command string without looping, which is simpler and faster. And more elegant. :)
- Has to use [dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).
- The updated version excludes columns defined `NOT NULL` and only updates each row ***once in a single statement***, which is much faster for tables with multiple character-type columns.
- Should work with any modern version of PostgreSQL. Tested with Postgres 9.1, 9.3, 9.5 and 13.