# Rank columns by their count of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, crosstab

I have a table with a bunch of boolean columns. I'd like to rank these columns by the count of true values each one has.

I found a way to count the number of true values in a column using:

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN col1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as col1,
       count(CASE WHEN col2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as col2
       ....
FROM my_table;
```

but this approach has two problems:

1. I have to manually type the names of the columns
2. I have to then transpose the result and order by value

Is there a way to do the whole operation one query?

Comment: Probably `crosstab` will handle it. Please provide http://sqlfiddle.com sample data and desired resultset

Comment: @lad2025 with `crosstab` you also have to manually type the names of the columns. Unless you use a dynamic statement, which is basically the same as buinding it the way OP presented (as far as result is concerned)

Comment: Edit your question and provide your desired resuls

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a crosstab job (or "pivot" in other RDBMS), but the reverse operation, "unpivot" if you will. One elegant technique is a `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` join.

The basic query can look like this, which takes care of:

> 2. I have to then transpose the result and order by value

```sql
SELECT c.col, c.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT count(col1 OR NULL) AS col1
        , count(col2 OR NULL) AS col2
          -- etc.
   FROM   tbl
   ) t
, LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('col1', col1)
   , ('col2', col2)
   -- etc.
   ) c(col, ct)
ORDER  BY 2;
```

That was the simple part. Your other request is harder:

> 1. I have to manually type the names of the columns

This function takes your table name and retrieves meta data from the system catalog `pg_attribute`. It's a dynamic implementation of the above query, safe against SQL injection:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_true_ct(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (col text, ct bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('
      SELECT c.col, c.ct
      FROM  (SELECT %s FROM tbl) t
           , LATERAL (VALUES %s) c(col, ct)
      ORDER  BY 2 DESC'
    , string_agg (format('count(%1$I OR NULL) AS %1$I', attname), ', ')
    , string_agg (format('(%1$L, %1$I)', attname), ', ')
      )
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl             -- valid, visible, legal table name 
   AND    attnum >= 1                 -- exclude tableoid & friends
   AND    NOT attisdropped            -- exclude dropped columns
   AND    atttypid = 'bool'::regtype  -- only character types
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_true_ct('tbl');  -- table name optionally schema-qualified
```

Result:

```
 col  | ct
------+---
 col1 | 3
 col3 | 2
 col2 | 1
```

Works for ***any*** table to rank all `boolean` columns by their count of `true` values.

To understand the function parameter, read this:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Check whether empty strings are present in character-type columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82030/3684)
- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621897/replace-empty-strings-with-null-values/10686513#10686513)

Comment: `LATERAL and VALUES` :) I always wonder why people want to simulate `SELECT *` behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a giant `union all`:

```
select c.*
from ((select 'col1' as which, sum(case when col1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt from t
      ) union all
      (select 'col2' as which, sum(case when col2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt from t
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) c
order by cnt desc;
```

Although you still need to type the results, this does sidestep the transpositions.