# Replace 'n/a' with 'NA' in all columns of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, dynamic-sql, psql

How to update *ALL* columns of a table in PostgreSQL? Rather than doing them one column at a time.
Given this table:

```
Table1
Field1 | Field 2 | Field 3
123    | 987     | n/a
456    | n/a     | 101
n/a    | abcdef  | n/a
```

The result should be:

```
Table1
Field1 | Field 2 | Field 3
123    | 987     | NA
456    | NA      | 101
NA     | abcdef  | NA
```

I am looking for a *single* SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `UPDATE` command dynamically from the system catalogs in a `DO` statement or plpgsql function for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_global_replace(_tbl regclass
                                          , _old text
                                          , _new text
                                          , OUT updated_rows int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   -- basic char types, possibly extend with citext, domains or custom types:
   _typ  CONSTANT regtype[] := '{text, bpchar, varchar}';
   _sql  text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql     -- build command
          format('UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE $1 IN (%s)'
               , _tbl
               , string_agg(format('%1$s = CASE WHEN %1$s = $1 THEN $2 ELSE %1$s END', col), ', ')
               , string_agg(col, ','))
   FROM  (
      SELECT quote_ident(attname) AS col  -- escape names, prevent SQL injection!
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl              -- valid, visible, legal table name 
      AND    attnum >= 1                  -- exclude tableoid & friends
      AND    NOT attisdropped             -- exclude dropped columns
      AND    atttypid = ANY(_typ)         -- only character types
      ORDER  BY attnum
      ) sub;

   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;             -- debug

   IF _sql IS NULL THEN
      updated_rows := 0;                         -- nothing to update
   ELSE
      EXECUTE _sql USING _old, _new;
      GET DIAGNOSTICS updated_rows = ROW_COUNT;  -- Report number of affected rows
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This assembles and automatically executes a query of the form:

```
UPDATE table1
SET    field1 = CASE WHEN field1 = $1 THEN $2 ELSE field1 END
     , field2 = CASE WHEN field2 = $1 THEN $2 ELSE field2 END
     , field3 = CASE WHEN field3 = $1 THEN $2 ELSE field3 END
WHERE  $1 IN (field1,field2,field3);
```

***Careful!*** The function updates all character type columns. Be sure it works as expected. For safety I suggest to run it inside an explicit transaction and only commit after checking:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM f_global_replace('table1'::regclass, 'n/a', 'NA');

TABLE table1;  -- all good?

COMMIT;  -- then commit; else ROLLBACK;
```

Related answers with more information and links:

- [Set empty strings ('') to NULL in the whole database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459106/set-empty-strings-to-null-in-the-whole-database/38462345#38462345)
- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621897/replace-empty-strings-with-null-values/10686513#10686513)

Comment: @NitinGoel: If that answers your question, [consider accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).