# PostgreSQL: ILIKE in all text columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

Is there a simple ad-hoc way to execute a `ILIKE` query on all text columns of a table?

I know that there is a cell which contains "foobar". But the table has a lot of columns and only 50k rows, so searching all columns and rows should be fast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm giving you this query with the understanding that this is NOT something you'd use for performance, just backfill and cleanup (which seems to be the case here):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename foo 
WHERE LOWER(foo::text) LIKE '%foobar%'
```

If you want to implement some moderately performant free text searching, you'd want to go through the effort of creating an indexed tsvector/weighted tsvector column.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Great! Just cast the whole thing to "text". Thank you!

Comment: BTW, why do you create the alias "foo"? works fine without it.

Comment: It's not really necessary, but it is a good habit to get into. Inevitably, ad hoc queries will evolve into massive behemoths with joins and correlated subqueries, but here, it saved me a few characters of typing.

Answer (score 0):

To be unambiguous, you can write:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename foo
WHERE  foo.*::text ILIKE '%foobar%';
```

A nested column of the same name (`foo` in this case) would take precedence. The more verbose syntax `foo.*` makes it an unambiguous reference to the table row.

About `LIKE` vs. `ILIKE` (and index support):

- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336665/lower-like-vs-ilike/20337500#20337500)

Closely related:

- [SQL: Search for a keyword in several columns of a table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7231/9501)
- [PostgreSQL: Cast row to type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/247261/3684)

For a more targeted search (fails the "ad-hoc" requirement), to only include string-type columns in the search, and exclude corner-case false positives that the above can produce, you could use dynamic SQL along these lines:

- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621897/replace-empty-strings-with-null-values/10686513#10686513)