# Coalesce function not selecting data value from series when it exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code is as follows:

```
Insert Into dbo.database (Period, Amount)
Select coalesce (date_1, date_2, date_3), Amount FROM Source.dbo.[10]
```

I'm 100% a value exists in one of the 3 variables: date_1, date_2, date_3, all as strings (var char 100), yet I am still getting blanks when I call Period.

Any help?

Comment: Are there date_1 and date_2 and date_3 in source.dbo.[10]?

Comment: Can you create a SQL fiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: The problem is, I believe the coalesce function is recognizing the date_1 blank as a value, rather than seeing nothing is there and skipping to date_2.  All the dates are defined as strings with varchar 100.

Comment: Well, I think your first problem may be storing dates in string-type fields (and `VARCHAR(100)`?  what?), and then using a _blank_ instead of null for 'no value'/'unknown'.  Convert them to actual date/time/timestamp fields, and use nulls, and this problem'll clear right up...

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce is designed to return the first NOT NULL field from the list or NULL if none of the fields are NOT NULL, follow the link for full details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

I would guess that you have blank values (' ') in one of the columns instead of NULL values.  If you are trying to find the first not null non-blank column you can use a case statement.

```
select 
 case
 when len(rtrim(ltrim(date_1))) > 0 then date_1
 when len(rtrim(ltrim(date_2))) > 0 then date_2
 when len(rtrim(ltrim(date_3))) > 0 then date_3
 else null
 end,
Amount
from Source.dbo.[10]
```

Comment: I think you have identified the problem, but is there a simpler way to skip over not null blank fields in the coalesce function?

Comment: Not really, coalesce is designed to find the first not null field.  You'd have to either write a function to return blanks as NULL or case each field in the coalesce to return a null if the field only has a blank value, I'll update my answer with a link to the coalesce details.

Comment: Thanks.  The databases I am pulling from are very large.  Would it be more efficient to do something like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701812/convert-empty-space-to-null

Comment: Or how about: SELECT IFNULL(NULLIF(col1,''),col2)

Comment: @Hype: really the best option is to use the date type, or a related type, instead of varchar. That would solve this problem once, instead of you having to solve it in every query.