# How to replace blank with Null across the select Statement in sql query

Tags: sql, performance

I have a sql query which has 290 columns in SELECT statement. I need to apply a condition when any of the columns values is '' or only , then replace it with `NULL` across the columns... any help?

I can use case statement but writing 290 times does not serve the purpose... so any other alternative..

Comment: 290 columns in select ??? and you have tagged it with `Performance` ..

Comment: Perhaps because of a performance problem?

Comment: Don't store those values!

Comment: we have junk data...

Comment: i can use coalesce function or isnull but i dont want to apply for each n every column individually... any universal function available...

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12742711/2224701

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert empty space to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701812/convert-empty-space-to-null)

Answer (score 0):

Better handle all your logic in your programming language.
You can use this:

```
select  DECODE(<column name>, '', '1', '0') from <tablename>
```